# Uploading lat and long to umap/osm using python

Tags: python-3.x, openstreetmap

I have a python script that enables me to get from openstreetmap the latitude and longitude, but I'm looking now how to create a custom map in OSM (or uMap) that allows me to upload a bunch of lat,lon coordenates and add a point in the map for each lat,lon pair. I know I can upload manually a csv file, but there are many points to put in the map and I can't upload a batch of 100k points in a single csv file. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Following the answer of @Michael2, I created a new map and try to do the post request. However, I'm a little bit confused with the map id and the layer id.

If I create a new map, lets call it "`mymap`", then the ID would be "`mymap_64813`" or just "`64813`"? The "`64813`" is a number that umap gives me. And I can't figure out where to find the layer id :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uMap, you can emulate the POST request that umap uses to store the GEOJSON data. Create a new map and note the id of the map, the id of the primary data layer (umap supports multiple layers per map) and your session cookie.

Then do a POST request to:

```
https://umap.openstreetmap.de/de/map/<id of the map>/datalayer/update/<id of the layer>/
```

Make sure to send along the cookies for the owner and the csrf-token

The content should be a multipart form request with the following fields:

- `name`: String of the layer name
- `display_on_load`: `true`
- `rank`: `0`
- `geojson`: A file with content type `application/json` and the actual point data in GEOJSON-Format.

To inspect this call, edit a sample map and have a look at the traffic between the client and the server using the web developer tools of your browser.

Comment: Hi @Michael2, thank you for the answer. The layer id is the name of the layer?

Comment: And also, sorry for the noob question, but how does the cookie for the owner and csrf-token works? I haven't done something similar before, so I'm looking at google all this. I did find a csrftoken cookie (?), but I don't know what to do with this. Also, I'm guessing that I need to use the requests python module, but how should I create the structure of the post request?

Comment: Hi @Michael2, I managed to get (I think) what is the map id and layer id. When doing the post request I'm getting "Forbidden" as a result. How is the structure of the content in the post request?

Comment: If you get a forbidden, you sent the wrong cookie and CSRF token.

Open your browser. Press F12. Go to the network tab. You will see all HTTP requests your browser does.

In your request, you need to include all the cookies + fields your browser sends. There are two authentication tokens you need to include: The first one is the CSRF token. It changes often and is just a security feature. The second one is your actual login. If one of those is wrong, you will not get an Error 403

Comment: Ohh I get it. Thank you @Michael2, I was viewing the CSRF token and the sessionid token in the application tab. I see a lot of things happening when I navigate and search locations. I tried to upload a single marker using just geojson structure, but I only saw a lot of .png data appear and only one data:image/gif file. How can I make the CSRF token appear in the list? Or I'm doing this wrong? I also guess that the login id token I should get it when I actually log in, right?